# qt 5 source build nmake failing

Tags: qt5

I'm trying to build qt 5 from the source files on Windows 7 64 bit using namke. Configure completes, but the nmake fails at some point saying in file gdom.h, invalid argument. I have Visual C++ 2010, Perl, and Python installed with the latest versions. Do I also need the Windows SDK? Will that make a difference? There seems to be a problem in the source file. Has anyone seen this? I have Windows 7 32 bit in a Virtual Machine. Maybe I'll try it there. Any input from someone is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Angle requires directx sdk too, and building Qt requires windows sdk, read [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/requirements-win.html) more details and see if you need directx sdk too.

Anyway there are already built with Visual Studio 2010 binaries to [download](http://qt-project.org/downloads), did you checked those to see if they are not enough for you

Comment: I got a static build to work on my Win 7 32 bit virtual machine and integrated the build into QT 5. So my application is deployable now. Still I'd like to get a successful build on my Win 7 64 bit host. Thanks for the replies guys. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

On my Windows 8 system compiling Qt5 without installing the Windows SDK failed. Here is how I compiled successfully Qt 5.0.1:

1. Install strawbey perl (http://strawberryperl.com/)
2. Install Windows SDK http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/aa904949 even when you are using Windows 7.  On older versions of Microsoft Windows the DirectX SDK should be installed.
3. Download Qt 5.0.0 source code from http://qt-project.org/downloads
4. Start “VS2012 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt“
5. Make sure that python is available on the command prompt. When installing Python you can add python.exe to the environment path. (I used python 3.3)
6. Switch to Qt 5.0.0 source directory (directory which contains configure.exe)
7. Run `configure -developer-build -opensource -nomake examples -nomake tests`
8. and afterwards `namke`